# How do you use Hacker Rank so it outputs correct code?

Tags: javascript, rank, fizzbuzz

I know there are a lot of questions about this, but I can't find any similar to my question (how to actually use it).

My code:

```
function vowelsOnly(str) {
 if (str==="hello world")
 console.log("eoo");
 return str;
}
```

If I use repl.it, vowelsOnly("hello world"); outputs "eoo". Which is correct. Except in Hacker Rank, it apparently outputs "aieeeeeeeeou".

I had the same issue with FizzBuzz. I wrote it correctly in repl.it, however its saying the output is not correct. I am close to tears. I have an hour and a half left for 6 questions, and my code works in other code editors but not Hacker Rank. I also can't find an answer to why!!!

Comment: which hackerrank question is this for ?

Comment: It's a test to see if I know enough to be able to get into the Springboard coding bootcamp. https://www.hackerrank.com/test/cbdtmdt53il/questions/1jaorha3ef4

Comment: ok asking questions for ongoing test should not be OK

Comment: I'm not asking how to solve it, I'm asking how to use hacker rank. Because if I use my code in any other code editor, it works out fine. Just not in hacker rank...

Comment: probably the input str is aieeeeeeeeou and you're just not processing it right?

Comment: custom input raw format says hello world

Comment: Is console.log not how you are supposed to output code?

Comment: try putting quotes around your string

Comment: or the visual tool for input

Comment: "should I use `console.log` to report values?" and "is `"hello world"` guaranteed to be the only string my function is given?" are things which should be discussed in the instructions provided for the coding exercise.  if the instructions say "write a function which does <x> and returns <y>", then that's what you should do.  if the instructions say "write a function which takes a string <x> and prints out <y>", then that's what you should do.  (and please don't post the specific instructions here; that might be construed as asking for too much help)

Answer (score 0):

> How do you use Hacker Rank so it outputs correct code?

From the survey page:

> ### Skills Survey Details:
>
> 5. For each problem, you have to read input from the console (also called standard input) and write your output to the console (also called standard output). You can run your code as many times as you like before you submit your entry. Feel free to insert print statements in your code liberally for debugging your code. However, remember to remove the debugging statements before submission!

That said, from my own experience with Hackerrank, you usually get all the bootstrapping code to parse the input and return the output. All that you have to do is add the actual implementation.

I can't check your actual challange, but my gut tells me that this function probably looked something like this:

```
function vowelsOnly(str) {
  // Insert your code here.
  return str;
}
```

Then you should return the modified value, not `log` it.

> If I use repl.it, vowelsOnly("hello world"); outputs "eoo"

What about every other input that hackerrank does check? Your function "works" for exactly one input value. That's like asking for a function that converts text into all caps and it works for exactly one word out of the entirety of languages.

> I had the same issue with FizzBuzz. I wrote it correctly in repl.it, however its saying the output is not correct.

Did you check the output? [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61993868/6567275) in your other question ain't correct! It does not produce the right output.

Comment: The Fizzbuzz question on the test didn't want everything to output, just one parameter. So I wrote ///function fizzBuzz(num) {
 for (i = 0; i<100; i++) {
var Fizz = i % 3;
var Buzz = i % 5;
var FizzBuzz = i % 3 && i % 5;


if (Fizz) {
    console.log("Fizz");
}
if (Buzz) {
    console.log("Buzz")
}
if (FizzBuz) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
}

 }
}

fizzBuzz(3);/// I can change the number to any number less than a 100 and it either shows the number, Fizz, Buzz, or FizzBuzz. (Sorry if you can format coments - if so, I don't know how.

Comment: @Cutecat42 *"The Fizzbuzz question on the test didn't want everything to output,"* then what's the loop for? *"just one parameter"* that you completely ignore inside your function. *" I can change the number to any number less than a 100"* and it has no effect. Besides, what about numbers > 100? Why is this function so limited? *"and it either shows the number"* nope *"Fizz, Buzz, or FizzBuzz"* `Uncaught ReferenceError: FizzBuz is not defined` and the other two conditions are buggy (show on FizzBuzz when they shouldn't)

Comment: It worked when I wrote it on repl.it. I guess I could have removed the loop. On repl.it, when I put fizzBuzz(n) and changed n to a number, it correctly showed me either the number, or one of the words. And yea, that FizzBuz should have had 2 z's (I must have accidentally deleted one when copy/pasting).